# "a" showing up with files during tar archiving

Tags: tar

While I'm archiving the file in my local system, I see an "a" at the beginning of the files while compressing.

```
tar -zcvf database.tgz database/
a database
a database/GeoIP2-City.mmdb
a database/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb
a database/GeoIP2-Domain.mmdb
a database/GeoIP2-ISP.mmdb
```

I have copied the archived file to the remote server and tried extracting it. But I have been through the following error. The file is not properly getting extracting and throwing errors. Below are the few lines of the error.

But when I do archiving of existing files in the remote servers I don't see "a" at the beginning of the lines, yet I was successful in extracting the file.

```
-bash-3.2$ tar -zxvf database.tgz 
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
./._database
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `LIBARCHIVE.creationtime'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
database/
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword
```

So, does it mean the file has not been properly archived?

Comment: It's just the v flag telling you that it's Adding files to the archive.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using [MAC OS](http://lifeonubuntu.com/tar-errors-ignoring-unknown-extended-header-keyword/) It turns out this is just an issue with tar files created on Mac OS X. Mac OS X uses BSD tar and creates some extra info that is not recognized by GNU tar.

**Solution: Don’t Worry About It**

What should you do about this? You don’t need to do anything. Your files will be extracted correctly, so you can safely ignore these warnings or errors.

Or You can Try to use command :

Tar files:

```
tar -cvf database.tgz database/
```

Untar files:

```
tar -xvf database.tgz database/
```

- c – Creates a new .tar archive file.
- v – Verbosely show the .tar file progress.
- f – File name type of the archive file.
- x -- extract tar file.